# PowerBI: Advanced filtering using data modelling to create dependent dropdowns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have created a **dimension table filter** which is modelled from 2 tables

[image]

Query for someone who has the same problem in the future -

```
calcProjectNameFilter = DISTINCT(
UNION(
VALUES('Vani_Trends actual'[Project Name]),
VALUES('Vani_Trends2 - planned'[Project Name])
)
)
```

Now I want to create another filter- phase name but it should be dependent on the selected project name. My attempt was to do something like -

```
calcProjectNameFilter = CALCULATETABLE( DISTINCT(
UNION(
VALUES('Vani_Trends actual'[Project Name]),
VALUES('Vani_Trends2 - planned'[Project Name])
),
ALLSELECTED(calcProjectNameFilter)
))
```

but that didn't work. Can anybody help me with creating dependent dropdowns using data modelling?

Comment: [Try this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8K4Px_6AYQ), maybe it can help you. Let me know if it does.

Comment: Does seem to do the trick. Put it in the answer so that I can accept it. Can you also tell me the difference between single/both cross filtering?

Comment: In Single Cross filtering only one table can filter out the other table, but another table cannot do the same thing, whereas in cross-filtering both tables can filter each other out. I've explained it in the answer section with pictures, let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8K4Px_6AYQ), maybe it can help you. Let me know if it does.

Single Vs Both Cross filtering:-

1. Single cross-filtering is enabled only one table can filter out the contents from the other table.

Table A can filter out the Table B

[image: A filters B]

But Table B can not filter Table A

[image: B cannot filters A]

2. In Both Cross-filtering Both Tables can filter out each other

Table A filters Table B

[image: A filters B]

Table B filters Table A

[image: B filters A]